# Какой частью речи выступает слово "ёб" в устойчивом сочетании "-- твою мать"?

Tags: грамматика, части-речи, обсценная-лексика

Всю жизнь, господа, говорю по-русски и теперь только задумался: а "ёб" — это частица или краткая форма известно какого глагола в прошедшем времени? Аргументируейте вашу точку зрения, пожалуйста.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87643/discussion-on-question-by-atas--------).

Comment: Друзья, дискуссия, которую вы устроили в комментариях, показательна во многом: пока вы выясняете отношения, люди на других сайтах дают ответы, помогают другим. Напоминаю, что только такое приемлемо на нашем сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну коль пошла такая пьянка...
Воспроизведу ссылку на свой ответ в другой части SE: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8528 
Там вопрос по-другому стоял, поэтому препарирую ответ под здешнюю формулировку.

1. Исторически это никакая не частица, хотя в современном исполнении какие-то доводы можно найти и в пользу частицы, но все равно это явный глагол даже сейчас, если говорить о грамматически правильной речи.
2. Вот насчет краткости формы сильно сомневаюсь. Тут скорее можно говорить о двух глаголах с разной системой лично-временных форм (исторической "ебсти" и более новой "еб@ть"). Поскольку табуированные слова обычно вообще и не имеют кодификации, то это привело к смешению всех форм - до такой степени, что автор вопроса на англоязычном форуме приплел сюда еще и давно исчезнувший аорист, *возможно, смешав его с еще более древним поссесивным перфектом (синтетическим, то есть выражавшемся без вспомогательных глаголов быть/иметь)*, чем окончательно всё запутал.

Я лично отношусь к этим двум буквам просто как к одной из форм прошедшего времени неправильного глагола. Остальное, в том числе и формулировка "краткая форма" - от лукавого. Углубляться здесь не хочу, не стоит овчинка выделки.

Answer (score -1):

Возьмём такой пример, где встретились два товарища:" - Ёб твою мать, ты себе налил больше, нежели мне! - восклицает первый. Второй же уточняет:- Простите,  милейший, надеюсь, слово" ёб" вы не использовали,  как глагол?!"   Если мы слово "ёб" определим частицей, вероятнее всего, спасём их дружбу. А так же здоровье.

Answer (score -4):

Первое что приходит на ум, это сокращение от глагола "ебать". Схожие альтернативы: "Мамку ебал", " Я твою мать ебал".